# Speeding up evaluation of power series, Python

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, cache

I want to plot (on the complex plane, with `mpmath`) the power series whose general term is the [number of partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of an integer.

The more points I want (and the larger the degree is), the longer the plot takes.

I first wrote a naive version, added memoization of the sequence, changed the naive evaluation of the polynomial with the [Horner algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method). All these modifications led to speed ups, and I want to know if there are more optimizations I could do.

```
import mpmath

MAX_DEGREE = 250
NB_POINTS = 40000


def memoize(function):
    memo = {}

    def wrapper(*args):
        if args in memo:
            return memo[args]
        else:
            rv = function(*args)
            memo[args] = rv
            return rv

    return wrapper


@memoize
def p_k(k, n):
    if k == 1 or k == n:
        return 1
    if k > n:
        return 0

    return p_k(k - 1, n - 1) + p_k(k, n - k)


@memoize
def p(n):
    res = 1
    for k in range(1, n):
        res = res + p_k(k, n)
    return res


def mgf(x):
    if abs(x) >= 1:
        return 0
    res = 0
    x_i = x
    for i in range(1, MAX_DEGREE):
        res = res + p(i) * x_i
        x_i = x_i * x
    return res


def mgf_horner(x):
    if abs(x) >= 1:
        return 0
    res = p(MAX_DEGREE)
    for i in reversed(range(1, MAX_DEGREE)):
        res = res * x + p(i)
    return res * x


if __name__ == "__main__":
    assert(p(1) == 1)
    assert(p(2) == 2)
    assert(p(5) == 7)
    assert(p(7) == 15)
    assert(round(mgf_horner(0.3), 8) == round(mgf(0.3), 8))
    assert(round(mgf_horner(0.5), 8) == round(mgf(0.5), 8))

    print("Tests passed!")

    mpmath.cplot(mgf_horner, points=NB_POINTS, re=[-1, 1], im=[-1, 1])
```

Comment: Do you want to *re-invent the wheel*? If not, consider using [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache).

Answer (score 2):

I think most savings are already achieved by the memoization. If you deconstruct the algorithms, your `mgf` and `mgf_horner` don't seem to do a lot different. The main difference is the direction of the summation, which affects the float rounding errors.

some small changes:

- instead of `reversed(range(1, MAX_DEGREE))` you can use `range(MAX_DEGREE - 1, 0, -1)`
- you can use the built-in `sum` or `math.fsum` if you rewrite the formula's a bit

something like this:

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=MAX_DEGREE)
def p2(n):
    return sum((p_k(k, n) for k in range(1, n)), 1)

def mgf_fsum(x):
    if abs(x) >= 1:
        return 0
    return math.fsum(p2(i) * x ** i for i in range(1, MAX_DEGREE))

def mgf_horner_fsum(x):
    if abs(x) >= 1:
        return 0
    return math.fsum(p2(i) * x ** i for i in range(MAX_DEGREE, 0, -1))

def mgf_sum(x):
    if abs(x) >= 1:
        return 0
    return sum(p2(i) * x ** i for i in range(1, MAX_DEGREE))

def mgf_horner_sum(x):
    if abs(x) >= 1:
        return 0
    return sum(p2(i) * x ** i for i in range(MAX_DEGREE, 0, -1))
```

but this rounding has an effect on the results:

```
steps = 15
for x in range(1, steps, 1):
    print(x/steps, mgf(x/steps), mgf(x/steps)/mgf(x/steps), mgf_sum(x/steps)/mgf(x/steps), mgf_fsum(x/steps)/mgf(x/steps), mgf_horner(x/steps)/mgf(x/steps), mgf_horner_sum(x/steps)/mgf(x/steps), mgf_horner_fsum(x/steps)/mgf(x/steps))
```

> ```
> x mgf_value mgf mgf_sum mgf_fsum mgf_horner mgf_horner_sum mgf_horner_fsum
> 0.06666666666666667 0.07655349092586666 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
> 0.13333333333333333 0.17795095671821595 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
> 0.2 0.3152135557353453 1.0 1.0 0.9999999999999998 0.9999999999999998 0.9999999999999998 0.9999999999999998
> 0.26666666666666666 0.5067809825345801 1.0 1.0 1.0000000000000007 1.0000000000000007 1.0000000000000007 1.0000000000000007
> 0.3333333333333333 0.7853123419985341 1.0 0.9999999999999997 1.0 0.9999999999999999 1.0000000000000002 1.0
> 0.4 1.2130721483139313 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.9999999999999998 1.0 1.0
> 0.4666666666666667 1.9206394911829312 1.0 1.0 1.0000000000000004 1.0000000000000004 1.0000000000000004 1.0000000000000004
> 0.5333333333333333 3.2187202179248864 1.0 1.0 1.0000000000000004 1.000000000000099 1.000000000000099 1.000000000000099
> 0.6 5.9870712939827015 1.0 1.0 0.9999999999999999 1.000000000201781 1.0000000002017808 1.000000000201781
> 0.6666666666666666 13.435823754250293 1.0 0.9999999999999999 1.0000000000000002 1.0000001435010422 1.0000001435010424 1.0000001435010424
> 0.7333333333333333 43.087235122138615 1.0 1.0000000000000002 1.0 1.0000353393606511 1.0000353393606507 1.000035339360651
> 0.8 288.2244586544328 1.0 1.0000000000000004 1.0 1.0023338650736258 1.002333865073626 1.002333865073626
> 0.8666666666666667 6672.576615237916 1.0 0.9999999999999998 0.9999999999999994 1.0273438993019854 1.0273438993019859 1.0273438993019859
> 0.9333333333333333 379389.61410647386 1.0 0.9999999999999997 0.9999999999999999 1.0860986641621089 1.086098664162109 1.086098664162109
> ```

for these tests I limited MAX_`DEGREE` to `70`.

As you can see, the 3 methods with increasing iteration give a different result than the 3 methods with decreasing iterations, especially with values closer to 1

Once the `p(x)` are calculated and in memory, this goes pretty fast, and no noticeable difference between the algorithms